# Multiple modals won't close when clicked outside of it

Tags: javascript, css

I followed this tut here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp
The problem is when I create two such modals, the first one won't close when I click outside of it. Here's the jsfiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/j1smeu3c/

```
// Get the modal
var modal1 = document.getElementById('myModal1');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn1 = document.getElementById("myBtn1");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn1.onclick = function() {
    modal1.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal1.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal1) {
        modal1.style.display = "none";
    }
}

//////////////////////////

// Get the modal
var modal2 = document.getElementById('myModal2');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn2 = document.getElementById("myBtn2");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[1];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn2.onclick = function() {
    modal2.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal2.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal2) {
        modal2.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: in your close function, shouldn't it be if (event.target != modal2) or is that just a typo?  Currently it would only close if you clicked on the modal and not when you click outside of it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second declaration of `window.onclick` overwrites the first one. You should set both checks in one function.

```
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal2) {
        modal2.style.display = "none";
    }
    if (event.target == modal1) {
        modal1.style.display = "none";
    }

}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this using a loop and classes instead of ids?

Comment: @NoahOlsen Of course, but that would hide every modal, if that's what you're expecting.

Comment: var modals = document.getElementsByClassName("modal")
  for(var i = 0; i < modals.length; i++){
    modals[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
https://jsbin.com/vokazuqahu/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 0):

You have two window.onclick functions. Delete one of them and make one like this:

```
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal1) {
        modal1.style.display = "none";
    }
    if (event.target == modal2) {
        modal2.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```